# Get type right when nesting Mongoose models in Typescript using interfaces

Tags: mongoose, typescript

I have a module with an interface for a Mongoose schema that looks like this:

```
// Interface
export interface User extends PassportDocument
{
    person: ObjectId | Person
}

// Mongoose Schema
var schema = new PassportSchema({
    person: { type: ObjectId, required: false, ref: 'Person' }
};
```

My problem is that when I populate `person` on a `User` document I don't understand how to get the typing right.

```
.then((user: User) => {
  console.log(user.person._id); // Property '_id' does not exist on type 'ObjectId | Person'
}
```

How do I solve this so I still can use types without creating a new interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [user defined type guards.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-defined-type-guard-functions)

Assuming that the person interface is the one containing the _id property,

```
function isPerson(potentialPerson:any) : potentialPerson is Person {
    // person-checking logic.
}

.then((user: User) => {
    if(isPerson(user.person)) {
        console.log(user.person._id); // should work now, user.person is understood to be of type 'Person'
    }
}
```

Comment: You have forgot a `:` after the params, it's less than 6 chars so I can't edit it. Otherwise it works like a treat so thank you! Now I just have to figure out why Gulp is giving me an error despite that everything is working...

Comment: My linter no longer gives me any warnings but when compiling I get `activities.ts(105,91): error TS2339: Property '_id' does not exist on type 'ObjectId | Person'.`. Everything is working as excepted though in the application itself when running it. Any ideas what has happened?

Comment: @Oskar ah you're right, thank you. I've updated the code. As for your second comment, are you continuing to access it in the code block of the if statement? It's only confirmed to be a Person type there. The type of the var outside that scope doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, I did something similar to `var personId = typeDefHelpers.isPerson(user.person) ? user.person._id : null`.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? These showed up in 1.6 I believe.

Comment: 1.7.3 so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Do you possibly have a version of typescript in your local node_modules that your gulp plugin may be using? If you just call `tsc` directly does that error come up?

Comment: Globally I have 1.8.9 installed of tsc. Unfortunately I have refactored away the line of code that gave the error. :/